# Rails not recognizing inherited class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a rails application which is an API. I am bypassing active record writing my own super class which is responsible for making api calls.
It appears that Rails does not like certain method names in the parent and accepts others. When I call `ModelClass.parent_method`, I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method parent_method' for ModelClass:Class):`
My code is structured like this:

```
 #./lib/accounts_api
 module AccountsAPI
   class SomeOtherClass
     . . .
   end

   class AccountModel
     class << self

       #this method works without fail:
       def get id
        url = "path to fetch object"
        response = HTTParty.get(url)
        return self.new response.parsed_response
       end
       # this method cannot be found
       def update_existing options   
        url = "path to update object"
        response = HTTParty.put(url, :body => options)
        return self.new response.parsed_response
       end
    end
 end
```

And then, a derived class:

```
class BankAccount < AccountsApi::AccountModel
  attr_accessor :id, :customer_id, :reference
  def initialize(options={})
    if options.respond_to? :each
      options.each do |key,val|
        target = "#{key}=".to_sym
        self.send(target, val) if self.respond_to?(target)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my controller, where the error is originating from:

```
class BankAccountsController < ApplicationController
  #Works just fine without fail
  def show
    @bank_account = BankAccount.get params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @bank_account, :status => :ok }
    end
  end
  #Throws:
  # NoMethodError (undefined method `update_existing' for BankAccount:Class):
  # app/controllers/bank_accounts_controller.rb:21:in update
  # without fail
  def update
    @bank_account = BankAccount.update_existing params[:bank_account]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @bank_account, :status => :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I've ommited some internals from the methods (error handling, validations, assignment etc.) for clarity.

A Workaround Fix:

If I change the `update_existing` method name to something more railsy, like `put`, it works just fine.

What else is weird, is that there is no Stacktrace. I'm just seeing the `Rendered rescues layout` messages in the logs:

```
Rendered /home/eggmatters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@my-gemset/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered /home/eggmatters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@my-gemset/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered /home/eggmatters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@my-gemset/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (7.0ms)
Rendered /home/eggmatters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@my-gemset/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.6ms)
```

More weirdness, Calling the method from the irb works just fine:

```
> options = {:id => "23", :customer_id => "123", :reference => "update"}
> BankAccount.update_existing options
=> (:bank_account => { {:id => "23", :customer_id => "123", :reference => "update"}, :id => "23"}
```

So I'm guessing, I'm messing with Rails messaging. I'm also guessing that my AccountModel parent class needs to inherit something from ActiveRecord or another rails lib but, this is too much of a bizarre edge case (to me) to research it.

Note: The AccountsAPI module is set to include in my `app/initializers` directory.

Also, I forgot to mention, restarting Passenger and or Apache has no effect.

UPDATE: Strike the Temporary Fix / workaround. Changing the method name to `put` still does not work. I can get it to update if I restart passenger a bunch of times, but it will only work once or twice and then back to the issue.

UPDATE: I cannot call a method on the child model either. In the model, I added the method:

```
class BankAccount < AccountsApi::AccountModel
  . . .
  def self.update_wrapper options
    return self.update options
  end
  . . .
end
```

Now throws:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_wrapper' for BankAccount:Class):
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the inclusion of the parent class within the module was somehow messing up the way rails was mapping methods. Pulling it out (and restarting Passenger) seemed to work:

```
class BankAccount < AccountModel
  . . .
end
```

and the parent:

```
module AccountsAPI
  class SomeOtherClass
  . . .
  end
end

class AccountModel
  class << self
    def get id
    . . 
    end

   def update_existing options   
       . . .
   end
end
```

Looks like it works. Not sure why though. I've seen the: `class Child < Module::Parent` pattern before. As I hinted at in my post, I'm missing some Railsy (possibly ruby) configuration aspect of this.

I caught this as another model (that just calls get) actually is an instance of the "SomeOtherClass" so, it would be exposed to the class within the module. I'm still open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Passenger was globally caching the module and not updating it on application restart. Moving the two classes to their own respective scripts in the lib folder as well as the module declaration altogether worked:

```
# ./lib/some_other_class.rb
class SomeOtherClass
  . . .
end

# ./lib/account_model.rb
class AccountModel
 . . .
end
```

Rails apparently maps these to the application level namspace so a declaration like:

```
class MySomeOtherClassModel < SomeOtherClass
```

and

```
class MyAccountModel < AccountModel
```

are found by rails as inclusion of the named libraries ensured inclusion by the application on load (i.e. server start)